# Determine the Smallest perfect square that is divisible by 7!?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hey can anybody help solving this question for me. 
Till now I have solved that it comes out to $7!= 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^1$ 
and now I'm confused about how to solve to find the smallest perfect square.

Comment: You will have the same prime factors but the powers must be even for it to be a square. Furthermore, you need to have atleast the same powers of the prime factors in order to be divisible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  if a number is a perfect square, all the primes that divide into it must ....?  You could try factoring all the squares up to $100$ for another hint.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close!!!

As you say: $7!= 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^1$

Now, for a number to be perfect square, the exponents in this prime factorization all need to be even. So ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

Except 5 and 7 other terms are complete square(in pairs).

So multiply with 5 and 7.

You get 176400 that is perfect and divisible by 7!.

Answer (score 0):

$n^2=\prod p_i^{2m_i}=7!*k=2^4*3^2*5*7*k$

$\frac {n^2}{2^4*3^2*5*7}=k $

$k=2^{2m_1 - 4}3^{2m_2-2 }5^{2m_3 - 1}7^{2m_4 -1}\prod p_i^{m_i} $.

What's the smallest we can make $k $?  Are any primes other than $2,3,5,7$ needed?  What power must we raise everything to make $7!k $ a square?